# Python - Using external XSLT file in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lxml, mathml

I'm using MathJax for a Python/Google App Engine CRUD webapp. I'd like for people to create equations using Content MathML (so that the webapp can leverage the semantic information elsewhere).

I then want to use [this Content-to-Presentation MML XSLT](http://code.google.com/p/web-xslt/source/browse/trunk/ctop) so that I can use MathJax on the resulting Presentation MathML.

Normally, I'd do something like this to provide the transformation service:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

class MathMLTranslator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with open('ctop.xsl') as f:
            self.xslt = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(f.read()))

    def translate(self, xml_string):
            return self.xslt(etree.XML(xml_string))
```

But I can't do `open('ctop.xsl')` in Google App Engine, nor can I just paste the contents of `ctop.xsl` as a string literal in MathMLTranslator (it's too big and has quotes of both types).

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can open files that were uploaded as part of your app just fine on App Engine - you just have to make sure the path is relative to the app. For example, if `ctop.xsl` is in the same directory as your Python module, you can do this:

```
fh = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ctop.xsl')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GAE, but if you can upload Python files of arbitrary size, you can just write `ctop.xsl` contents to .py file. e.g. `ctop_data.py`:

```
ctop_xsl = """<xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
... SKIPPED
"""
```

Then in code you can:

```
from ctop_data import ctop_xsl
...
self.xslt = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(ctop_xsl))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could put the file on dropbox and use the dropbox API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET

I'd suggest python-requests for this purpose:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

I have not done this from google app engine, though I do have code running on heroku doing similar things.